# What is the difference between these two sentences?

Tags: grammar, particles

1)

> 元々恋愛と結婚は別のものと彼女は考えていた。

and

2)

> 元々彼女は恋愛と結婚は別のものと考えていた。

Would I be right in saying that

1) focuses on the fact that she thought marriage AND love were different

2) focuses on that it was HER who thought love and marriage were different

Also a little confused on the usage of particles at the end because 1) has は考えていた. What is the difference between は考えていた and を考えていた?

Thank you :)

Comment: Oops, I "corrected" を考えていた to と考えていた in Sentence 2 without thinking, but are you sure you are concerned about **を**考えていた? **を**考えていた doesn't make much sense to me, so please double-check.

Comment: Thank you! 
The first sentence is from a book and the second sentence is one I wrote because I was confused about the particles in the first sentence. Why does を考えていた not make sense?

Comment: @Ria [noun]を考えていた vs [clause]と考えていた (think that ~)

Answer (score 3):

They have the same meaning. The difference between these sentences is word order, and that's about it.

> 1. 元々恋愛と結婚は別のものと彼女は考えていた。
> 2. 元々彼女は恋愛と結婚は別のものと考えていた。

I'd translate:

> 1. Originally, love and marriage are different, she thought that.
> 2. Originally, she thought love and marriage were different.

Comment: If there's anything, 元々 "originally" has an ambiguity whether it's inside or outside what she thought in the first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> 元々恋愛と結婚は別のものと彼女は考えていた。
>   元々彼女は恋愛と結婚は別のものと考えていた。

I think that most Japanese think the two sentences have the same meaning.